# laravel properties search box

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i'm begginer and i need help with small Laravel 5.2 app.

All i wanna do, is to make working property search box with options for months and for years and fetch data from database when i checked values in property box.

Here is my form:

```
 <form action="{{ route('show') }}" method="get"> 
  <select name="month" id="meseci" required>
      <option value="Januar">Januar</option>
      <option value="Februar">Februar</option>
      <option value="Mart">Mart</option>
      <option value="April">April</option>
      <option value="Maj">Maj</option>
      <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
      <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
      <option value="Avgust">Avgust</option>
      <option value="Septembar">Septembar</option>
      <option value="Oktobar">Oktobar</option>
      <option value="Novembar">Novembar</option>
      <option value="Decembar">Decembar</option>   
  </select>
   <select name="year" id="godine" required>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>    
  </select>
  <button type="submit" value="search">Search</button>
  <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
</form>**
```

And this is my Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class ImageController extends Controller
{


public function index()
{

}

public function show(Request $request)
{
    $images = DB::table('images')
     ->whereMonth($request->month)
     ->whereYear($request->year)
     ->get();

        return view('show', ['images' => $images]);     
}
}
```

But after this i got Error:

Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereMonth(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\Http\Controllers\ImageController.php on line 22 and defined

here is pic my db

[image]

Any help and Info i will really appreciate?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$images = DB::table('images')
     ->where('month', '=', $request->month)
     ->where('year', '=', $request->year)
     ->get();
```

Comment: now send me to the blank page, there i no pictures.

Comment: try `dd($images)` let you know what is return.

Comment: i got this:  array:3 [▼
  "month" => "Februar"
  "year" => "2015"
  "_token" => "jKt2hflBJfwH2izPVdaLX0UfTtef2zuHrRcURn97"
]

Comment: i put it dd($request->all());  if i put dd($images) i got error: Undefined variable: images

Comment: `dd($images)`  this line put after the query.

Comment: i did...i have empty [] ...here is redirecting page:foreach ($images as $ima) {

 <ul>
  <li><img src="{{$ima->source}}" alt=""></li>
 </ul> 
}
endforeach     source is path to the images in database

Comment: your searching data exists or not in your `database` please check. and show me your existence images table data for easy to understand.

Comment: check it know! and `dd($images)` as above i said.

Comment: Cool.... it's working ...thanks mate you save me !!!!! :) can i vote for you somewhere, i cant here cuz i have just 6 reputation?

Comment: Happy to helped  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:

```
->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $request->month);
```

Comment: thank you for reply...Sorry i didnt write....i already have pictures in database with names(years,months) and i wanna fetch them after checking in property search..

Comment: Can you post your DB in your question?

Comment: i put it my DB up in task , please check